# Count from long to wide format

Tags: r

Having a long format like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2), text = c("stock","arrange","stock","arrange","arrange"))
```

How is it possible to receive the wide format of making the variables in text column new columns which have as values the number the exist?
Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2) stock = c(2,0), arrange = c(1,2))
```

Comment: Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36700028/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34417973/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37364249/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25007317/5325862), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47469412/5325862). This is a type of calculation that's been covered pretty extensively already, so it's helpful to first try looking at what posts are already out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you need it as a data.frame, here's an option with data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(df, id ~ text, fun.aggregate = length)
#    id arrange stock
# 1:  1       1     2
# 2:  2       2     0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `table` to get the frequency counts

```
table(df)
```

Comment: How to save the results in dataframe format?

Comment: @Nathalie `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))`